# QT project without opengl

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-construction, qmake

I made an application with qt c++ with does not need opengl

So I did configure qt with -no-opengl option while building.

I've compiled my project qith qmake from the qt build output.

Unfortunatly while running my application in "light xp" i get the error "opengl32.dll not found"

Does anyone already done this and could help me?

Thanks

Comment: are you sure you don't need openGL, QtQuick needs it behind the scenes

Comment: What version of Qt (4 or 5) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you've kept the source you built from this is pretty straight forward, just rerun configure with OpenGL enabled and make sure you've got the dependencies and Qt will build the module and deploy for you, if not you can try downloading the OpenGL part separately and build it from the source yourself or rebuild the entire Qt library from scratch.